# problema con alcance d e variables

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo un programa con tkinter  y python , la cual el usuario ingrese sus datos y  guarde sus datos para posterior mente ser guardados en una lista , despues a la base  datos que todavía no esta activa  y no tiene nada que ver  por el momento con este codigo .
el codigo es el siguiente .

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

ventana=Tk()
conexion = sqlite3.connect("base_registro")
cursor=conexion.cursor()


#-----------------FUNCIONES----------------------
usuario =[]
def crear():
    global nombre_usuario
    nombre_usuario = entrada_nombre.get()
    global apellido_usuario
    apellido_usuario= entrada_apellido.get()
    global direccion_usuario
    direccion_usuario = entrada_direccion.get()
    global contraseña_usuario
    contraseña_usuario = entrada_contraseña.get()
 #usuario.extend([direccion_usuario,contraseña_usuario])
print(nombre_usuario)
def actualizar():
    pass

def  leer(self):
    pass

def eliminar():
    pass

def enviar():
    pass

#--------------------------------------------------
nombre=Label(ventana,text="NOMBRE")
nombre.grid(row=1,column=0 )

entrada_nombre=Entry(ventana)
entrada_nombre.grid(row=1,column=1 )
#--------------------------------------------------
apellido=Label(ventana,text="APELLIDO")
apellido.grid(row=2,column=0 )

entrada_apellido=Entry(ventana)
entrada_apellido.grid(row=2,column=1 )
#--------------------------------------------------
direccion=Label(ventana,text="DIRECCION ")
direccion.grid(row=3,column=0 )

entrada_direccion=Entry(ventana)
entrada_direccion.grid(row=3,column=1 )

#--------------------------------------------------
contraseña=Label(ventana,text="CONTRASEÑA")
contraseña.grid(row=4,column=0 )

entrada_contraseña=Entry(ventana)
entrada_contraseña.grid(row=4,column=1 )

#----------------BOTONES--------------
crear=Button(ventana,text="crear", command=crear)
crear.grid(row=5,column=0)

#--------------------------------
leer=Button(ventana,text="leer")
leer.grid(row=5,column=1)


#--------------------------------
actualizar=Button(ventana,text="actualizar")
actualizar.grid(row=5,column=2,pady=2, padx=1)


#--------------------------------
eliminar=Button(ventana,text="eliminar")
eliminar.grid(row=5,column=3)


#--------------------CODIGO SQL -------------------

"""
usuario =[nombre,apellido,direccion,contraseña,correo]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES(?,?,?,?) ",usuario)

"""
#----------------------PRUEBAS-------------------

enviar=Button(ventana,text="enviar",command=enviar)
enviar.grid(row=6)
conexion.close()
ventana.mainloop()
```

pero al momento de guardar la información de en una lista:

```
usuario =[]
def crear():
    global nombre_usuario
    nombre_usuario = entrada_nombre.get()
    global apellido_usuario
    apellido_usuario= entrada_apellido.get()
    global direccion_usuario
    direccion_usuario = entrada_direccion.get()
    global contraseña_usuario
    contraseña_usuario = entrada_contraseña.get()
usuario.extend([direccion_usuario,contraseña_usuario])
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
usuario.extend([direccion_usuario,contraseña_usuario])
NameError: name 'direccion_usuario' is not defined
[Finished in 1.3s]
```

cuando ya le indique al programa que las variables son globales y las llame en el buton en la parte de tkinter  , por otro lado el get es la forma d eobtencion de datos a penas el usuario pulse el boton crear se activara la funcion y capturar alos datos

Answer (score 0):

el problema fue solucionado pero no borro la pregunta para enseñar a otra personas que les pase lo mismo

la solucion fue la siguiente:

el problema era  que el orden de orden de ejecución ya que al tener la lista dentro de la ventana de tkinter funcionaba como un scope local pero si se hacia fuera de `ventana.mainloop() se convertia en una variable global

**INCORRECTO**

```
print(usuario)
ventana.mainloop()

NameError: name 'nombre_usuario' is not defined
```

**correcto**

```
ventana.mainloop()
print(usuario)
[Finished in 6.9s]
```

`